# Spring Data JPA unique criteria

Tags: jpa, spring-data

i updating my old project to spring data jpa, so in my old project i am checking unique filed value in db like the below

```
@Override
    public <K extends AbstractDomainObject> boolean isUnique(Class<K> clazz, Map<String, Object> properties) {
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer("select count(obj) from "+ clazz.getSimpleName() +" obj where 1=1");
        Iterator<String> iterator = properties.keySet().iterator();
        logger.info("EntrySet: " + properties.entrySet());
        while(iterator.hasNext()) {
            String key = iterator.next();
            stringBuffer.append(" and "); 
            stringBuffer.append("obj."+key+"='"+properties.get(key)+"'");
        }

        Query query = entityManager.createQuery(stringBuffer.toString());
        Long resultCount = (Long) query.getSingleResult();
        logger.info("### Result Count for isUnique: " + resultCount);
        return  ((int)(resultCount == null?0:resultCount)) <= 0;
    }
```

this code is working perfect, **how could i convert this into Spring Data jpa,**

i am passing values like this i have sevice and implementation

```
public class CountryService {
    public boolean isUnique(Country country, Map<String, Object> params);
}

public class CountryServiceImpl{
    @Autowire
    GenericDAO genericDAO;

    @Override
    public boolean isUnique(Country country, Map<String, Object> params){
        genericDAO.isUnique(country, params);
    }
}
```

In My Controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMappin("/country")
public class CountryController{

    @Autowire
    CountryService countryService;

    @ReqeustMapping("/unique")
    public String checkUnique(@ModelAttribute("country")Country country, ModelMap modelMap, HttpServletRequest request){
         Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
         params.put("code", country.getCode());
         params.put("name", country.getName());
         countryService.isUnique(Country.class,
    }
}
```

The above code is perfectly fine, by this i need to use spring jpa specification in my genericDAO, i guess by using Predicate in jpaspecification, please help me out here, below code is a guess i think

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<K> query = builder.createQuery(clazz);
        Root<K> root = query.from(clazz);

        return entityManager.createQuery(query.select(root)).getResultList();
```

Comment: need expertise comment here plz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fulfill your "genericDao" requirement, you would need a custom repository class similar to the one you already have. Then, solving this with pure JPA, you could use a method like the following:

```
public List<T> findByParameters(String param1, String param2, String value1, String value2) {
        CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<T> criteria = cb.createQuery(getEntityClass());
        Root<T> root = criteria.from(getEntityClass());
        criteria.select(root);
        criteria.where(cb.and(cb.equal(root.get(param1), value1), cb.equal(root.get(param2), value2)));
        return entityManager.createQuery(criteria).getResultList();
    }
```

You would still have to call that method and then see if it returns a list of size greater than 1.
Of course, this can easily be made more dynamically. Please see [this pastebin](http://pastebin.com/hiVQjyES) containing 2 classes I created when first playing around with JPA.

Comment: thx for your replay its really helpfull your answer, thanks very much, i am implementing like you provide pastebin code, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Following will be your respository.

```
public interface CountryRepository extends CrudRepository<Country, Integer> {   
    public List<Country> findByCodeAndName(Integer code,String name);
}
```

Your CountryService isUnique() will have the following.

```
private boolean isUnique(Integer code,String name) {
   Iterable<Country> iterable= countryRepository.findByCodeAndName(code,name);
    return iterable.iterator().hasNext();
}
```

If you have any doubts, Please check the SQL generated and refer documentation [2.4.2](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/)